# Is it possible to run Windows Server 2008 R2 on Amazon EC2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to run Windows Server 2008 R2 on Amazon EC2? Is it possible to upload your own images of operating systems to Amazon EC2?

Comment: What did Amazon say when you asked them?

Comment: I havn't asked Amazon - if you want any tech support - at all - even if its their fault - you have to sign up for a rolling $100/month "deluxe silver plated tech support package". Go figure.

Comment: then don't contact tech support. Call sales instead. These are matters that need to be clarified before signing up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Launched!

http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2011/03/16/introducing-support-for-windows-server-2008-r2-on-amazon-ec2/

> We are pleased to announce that we have added support for Windows Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server Standard 2008 R2.
>
> Windows Server 2008 R2 includes many exciting new features, such as support for IIS 7.5, additional Active Directory features, new management tools, and performance improvements when deployed on Amazon EC2.

Answer (score 2):

To my big surprise, Windows 2008 **R2** is not yet supported, see this [forum post](http://bit.ly/ez6zW1)

Plus, you can not upload your own *Windows* images (license issue, I think it works for Linux).

Comment: Thanks. The reason I'd love R2 is that R1 is basically Vista under the hood, its slow as a dog and has compatibility issues. R2 is basically Win 7, its is an order of magnitude better in most respects. Amazon - please support R2!

Answer (score 1):

[This forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=215817&#215817) from an Amazon employee (on January 13 2011) says that there is still no date announced for Server 2008 R2 AMIs.